# Check to see if website is loaded via Iframe

Tags: javascript, php

I have index.php as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="Description">
<meta name="keywords" content="Keyword1, Keyword2">
</head>
<body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
<iframe id="myID" src="/index2.php" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" >
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

The iframe in index.php is used to mask index2.php (i.e. iframe src). The user can however simply enter the website through

```
www.website.com/index2.php
```

which would undermine all masking. Is there a way to know via javascript or other means whether iframe is loaded on each of the website's pages and redirect user if they have entered the site via index2.php.

Comment: I smell [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: How could I improve on what I said?

Comment: I think the question is valid, it's perfectly understandable

Comment: Well, I wonder why you want to "mask" `index2.php` and why you have an `index.php`, an `index2.php` and a bunch of `iframes`in the first place. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Comment: @JuanBonnett: never said otherwise. But I have a slight suspicion that OP's *actual* end goal could be achieved in a less awkward fashion. I could be wrong, of course.

Comment: Tobia, I appreciate the feedback. I am sure you are right in some sense. Everything could be done less awkwardly than I attempt it. As for what I am trying to do, I am attempting to mask my url and I chose an iframe to reach my goal. The reason I have index2.php is because I can't directly input the php code into the iframe.

Comment: @SamKingston do note that you are not "masking" much this way, the URL is just one `Shift+Ctrl+Q` in Firefox away. So I wonder if you are doing this for security reasons (uh, *bad idea*) or for usability reasons (I'd bet it's not that good an idea either). So the real question is: why you want to hide your URL? If you are not mantaining a legacy system which came this way I'd consider rethinking your approach - note in particular that some mobile browsers tend to work funny with `iframe`s. (Obviously you might have your motives, all considered - I don't know the full story :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a way you can do this reliably. You either need to use JavaScript within the iframe page to test if the document is in the `top` frame, or use PHP to check the referrer.

Place one of the following in the page you want loaded inside the iframe.

**PHP**

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'http://domain.com/index.php') {
header('Location: http://domain.com/index.php');
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
if (window==window.top) { 
window.location = "http://domain.com/index.php"
}
```

**NB**
However, since JavaScript can be turned off, and the referrer can be spoofed, it's never going to be entirely foolproof.

Possibly the best remedy would be to replace the iframe with an include and update it using AJAX.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where exactly would the javascript code be placed? Anywhere in the iframe page?

Comment: The PHP must be placed before anything is sent to the browser, otherwise you'll get a headers already sent error. Easiest way to do this is to put it at the VERY top. The JavaScript can be anywhere in the head or body of the page, but in the head would probably be best.

Comment: While it is the only way that I can think of as well, I must warn OP that going this route is the second best thing to being put in a time machine and going straight back to 1998.

Comment: That is why they are both conditionals, if the page is loaded through an iframe, it shouldn't do anything. @TobiaTesan - Yes, it isn't ideal, hence my suggestion for using includes and AJAX, which is fundamentally a better practice.

Comment: Hi Geoff, Tried the javascript comment at the top of index.php. It causes a permanent refresh and the site never gets loaded. I placed exactly as you had written it.

Comment: No, the page *within* this iframe. Sorry if I wasn't clear. It would in the `index2.php` file.

Comment: You are the mannn. Thank you so much. I appreciate your time.

Comment: The` HTTP_REFERER` works well where spoofing isn't an issue on a site where javascript would be painful (the website is rendered by PHP which then runs javascript which then completely re-renders the page because it knows now that it's in an iframe.